# I can't get array PHP encode in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I can't find index in json array.
The browser show me undefined data.
I posted below sequence of code.

My array in PHP encode.

```
[{"voo_Cod":"1","voo_CidadeOrigem":"1","voo_CidadeDestino":"2","voo_Data":"2015-07-13 07:00:00","voo_Preco":"200"}]
```

My code in jquery

```
$("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

//receive data json php
    $.ajax({
        url: "dadosJSON.php",
        // dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(d) {
            alert(d);

            if(d[0].erro) {
                $("h2").html(d[0].erro);
            } else {
                var html = "";
                // var html = alert(d);

               //show result in html
                for($i = 0; $i < d.length; $i++) {
                    html += " <strong>Voo Data e Horario</strong> " +     d[$i].voo_Data;
                    html += " <strong>Preco</strong> " + d[$i].voo_Preco;
                }
            }

            $("body").html(html); 
        });
    });
});
```

My JASON php.

```
 <?php
require_once("./authSession.php");
require_once("./conf/confBD.php");
include_once("../html/cabecalho_main_Pessoal.html");

print_r($_POST);\\print array

\\array try catch
try{

    //conection PDO
    $conexao = conn_mysql();
    }catch(PDOException $excep){
    echo "Erro!: " . $excep->getMessage() . "\n";
    die();
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['cidadeOrigem'])){
    $cidOrigem   =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cidadeOrigem']));
    $CidDestino  =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cidadeDestino']));

   }else{ echo "Não contém arquivos";}

    $SQLSelect = 'SELECT * FROM voos WHERE voo_CidadeOrigem=? AND    voo_CidadeDestino= ?';

    $operacao   =  $conexao -> prepare($SQLSelect);

    $pesquisar  =  $operacao -> execute(array($cidOrigem, $CidDestino));

    $resultados = $operacao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
    $conexao = null;    

    \\show result
    foreach($resultados as $key=>$result) {
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($result); echo "</pre>";
    }

    \\get array, send json result
    $dados_result = json_encode($resultados);
    echo $dados_result;

?>
```

`Creates a loop undefined in browser response.

> `Voo Data e Horario undefined Preco undefined.`
>   \ error result

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Can you show what you get in the `alert(d)`?

Comment: Can you post your script in `dadosJSON.php`?

Comment: Ok, I posted Dave Chen.

Comment: My alert(d). Varun [{"voo_Cod":"1","voo_CidadeOrigem":"1","voo_CidadeDestino":"2","voo_Data":"2015-07-13 07:00:00","voo_Preco":"200"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your php array with json_encode php function and then print the array. Without encoding the array , you can't process the array with js.

```
    $arr = json_encode($array);
    print_r($arr);
```

Comment: JigoJonh, last line of  php code. I encoded array PDO by json. Thanks.

Comment: Jigo Jonh continue in browser undefined data. Thanks.

Comment: hey try making a demo json array using some online json creators, and then try to parse that json array with your jquery script.. if it's not working properly use a jquery foreach for looping your existing array @Augusto

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line

```
 // dataType: "json",
```

Comment: If you want to test your PHP by printing array, don't add datatype: json... Only add that if the return is in json format

Comment: I disable print, but continue show in browser undefined data. Thanks